# Big endian encoding in java socket from string

Tags: java, sockets, networking, encoding, packet

My requirement is to encode the string in the following format to send it over the java socket

Telegram is prefixed with a four byte length field arranged in network byte order (big-endian).

      `+-------------------------------- ... ------+ 
Byte  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |               | x | 
      +-------------------------------- ... ------+ 
Field | -- Data Length -- | Data                  | 
      +-------------------------------- ... ------+` 

For example, if the number of bytes in the telegram is 300 (0x012C), the length field is populated as follows: 

`+-------------------------------- ... ------+ 
| 00 | 00 | 01 | 2C | Data (300 bytes) | 
+-------------------------------- ... ------+`

how to I convert my java String in to this format?

eg: String request = "\Start\</request>" to what ever the format mentioned above

I tried request.getBytes("UTF8") but not compatible, its crashing (server is written in .NET). for me the server is a blackbox,

```
    final Socket SOCKET = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);

    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(SOCKET.getOutputStream(), "UTF8");

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/request.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
            buffer.append((char) ch);
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    ;
    String r = buffer.toString();


    char[] c = r.toCharArray();
out.write(c);
```

out.flush();

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    while (SOCKET.getInputStream().available() != -1) {
                        System.out.println(SOCKET.getInputStream().read());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just be converting the `String` to a `byte[]` (ideally with a fixed encoding, e.g. UTF-8) and then encoding that byte array as described? What have you tried, and what's the difficulty?

Comment: I tried request.getBytes("UTF8") but not compatible, its crashing (server is written in .NET). for me the server is a blackbox,

Comment: "not compatible" doesn't really give us any information. (You'd still need to encode that data with the length prefix, of course.) What encoding *does* the server expect? Without that information, we can't possibly help you.

Comment: What i mean by not compatible is the server is crashing with out any response. how to encode the data with that length prefix. Sorry as I am just a starter so my question might be very basic.

Comment: Well if you've tried using UTF-8 you must have some code that you've *tried* to encode the length prefix. You should include that in the question. (Hint: DataOutputStream will help you...)

Comment: yes!  I have updated

Comment: Um, you've only shown code which *reads* data. You haven't shown anything encoding the data and *writing* it to the server. (Additionally, please read the markdown guide to make your post easier to read...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataOutputStream has methods to write primitives in network byte order. In this case you want four bytes so you would use writeInt() to write the length word, then write the bytes.

You will probably want to put a BufferedOutputStream between the DataOutputStream and the socket output stream, and only flush it when you've written all parts of the message.

NB get rid of the available() test. Just block in the read() method if you're expecting a response.